# Failed to update auto layout status:failed to load designable from path (null)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, ibdesignable

When i am trying to set class i am getting IB Designables error.

I tried

1. Clearing derived data
2. pod update
3. Clean the Project
4. Quit and open project again
5. Build Project

But nothing is working.

I like to know this problem is arise due to pod or by Xcode ?

[image]

Comment: Please show code.

Comment: @shallowThought i didn't used code just changed the class for the view ,that HCSStarRatingView is a pod file class

Comment: if you want to see the pod class @shallowThought  ??

Comment: I had a short look in the Github repo, but couldn't spot a obvious issue. I never used it, most probably someone else did and can help.

Comment: ok lets see if i use other pods getting the same issues :( @shallowThought